# Can we support Latex formulas on this site?

Tags: feature-request

There are some SE sites that have already supported Latex formulas, but this site hasn't. Can we provide the support here? 
For example, I would like to have the Latex formulas rendered in [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/how-to-compute-the-present-value-of-a-liability).
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Admittedly, I'm not a regular contributor to this site.  I speak mainly as a contributor to Code Review, where we [recently had MathJax enabled](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/9357).  So far, the reaction in the Code Review chat room has been overwhelmingly positive, and performance impact has been negligible, even on mobile devices.  To avoid unintentionally triggering MathJax, Code Review has opted to use `\$` instead of `$` as delimiters (following in the footsteps of [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)).

By not supporting MathJax, Personal Finance & Money is probably missing out on many good questions and answers, such as [Math for Future Value of Growing Annuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767888/77144), which went to Math SE instead.

While it is possible to get by without MathJax by resorting to [LaTeX-like ASCII symbols](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/10070/14744), good notation aids effective communication.  The Math SE example above would just be too complex for any pseudo-LaTeX notation.  Also, MathJax doesn't just let you write formulas — you can also create [tables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40821/9357).

Should the Personal Finance & Money community decide to pursue MathJax, the Stack Exchange team will want to see a list of example posts as evidence that it would be beneficial.  It would be trivial to find good examples:

- [Monthly/Annual Payments Calculation with percentage increase to equal exact dollar amount over exact specified period](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/27509/14744)
- [Time-Weighted Rate of Return & Money-Weighted Rate of Return](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/26469/14744) (question and multiple answers)
- [Are Bond Coupons reinvested at YTM](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/24583/14744) (tables and formulas)
- [Is compounding interest on investments a myth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/27870/14744)
- [What is the formula for the Tesla Finance calculation?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/24725/14744)

Answer (score 8):

How many posts would this affect? The MathJax dependency is *extremely* heavy so we don't like to do this unless a plurality of posts on the site would benefit from adding this overhead to every single page load on the site.

Comment: Is this still true in 2019?

Answer (score 5):

I would NOT be in favor of supporting LaTeX on Money SE.
I say that as someone who is attracted to the StackExchange platform on other sites *because* of the LaTeX support.

The main reason I wouldn't support this is that on Money SE, I think people would more often than not *inadvertantly* go into math mode as soon as they typed a `$`.  Then they'd just be confused about why all of their text is italicized and all the spacing is messed up.  This happens on occasion in [Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/), where it's more reasonable to assume that the target users have some knowledge about LaTeX.

Initially I was disappointed to discover this site lacked LaTeX support when I wrote [my first answer here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/10070/4285).  But now I think the LaTeX support would be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Wouldn't using `\$` as the delimiter (as EE.SE does) completely negate this concern?

Comment: since Personal Finance has the possible frequent use of `$`, I wonder why if we use another symbol, such as `~` or `@`, to denote the start of MathJax.  Also, can we map `$` in MathJax to `~~` (2 of them) and `$$` to `~~~` (3 of them)... this way, there is even less possibility of the user accidentally using it.

Answer (score -2):

I thought to supplement user 200_success 's foregoing answer by tendering some more questions that require maths symbols and so would benefit from MathJax:

- https://money.stackexchange.com/a/23834/10763

Comment: In that case, it's clear the member would find it faster to post an image of a spreadsheet. Latex/etc probably would have slowed him down, not helped.