# Does Tex markup work on this site?

Tags: support, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we support Latex formulas on this site?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/can-we-support-latex-formulas-on-this-site)

I recently tried to format a financial formula using the Tex markup that I've seen used on some of the other math/science oriented stackexchange sites, but it didn't seem to work as I expected. To be fair, I've never used Tex markup before on any site, so I may have just been doing it wrong.

Is Tex markup something that is enabled on a site by site basis, and if so should it be enabled on this one?

I know most people on this site probably wouldn't use it but there are enough formulae that relate to personal finance that it seems like it would be nice to have for those of us who want to use it.

Comment: Hi Mike.  This question was asked already.  Please see Jeff Atwood's answer at the question linked to above.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisW.Rea. I guess I missed it because I was searching for Tex instead of LaTex.