# What really prevents us from enabling LaTeX markup?

Tags: feature-request

While not necessary for every question, LaTeX markup capability would greatly enhance the ability to clearly write some questions and answers in the personal finance and money stackexchange.  This would allow clean and clear math, symbols, and tables.

This question was asked a number of years ago [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/can-we-support-latex-formulas-on-this-site) and the top answer suggests that the overhead is significant.  Another answer suggests that using $ as a delimiter will mess a lot of people up.  However, [a later answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1972/19056) indicates that empirically, the overhead is actually negligible and the confusion issue is easily addressed by using \$ as the delimiter instead.

This question and all the answers are years old and in my view the objections have not aged well.

My question is this: Who makes the decision about utility of a feature versus costs of the overhead?  Where do we submit input on the subject?  The desirability of a change seems clear to me but I'm not sure whether it's being considered.  Is anything aside from inertia really keeping us from enabling this feature?

Answer (score 3):

The decision is ultimately made by the StackExchange team, and the way to influence that decision is to debate it on meta.

5 years ago Jeff Atwood [said](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454/366) it should only happen if "a plurality of posts" would benefit, given the size of the MathJax dependency. I'm not quite sure what he meant by a plurality, and perhaps the relative overhead is lower now, but I think we still need a decent argument that a lot of posts would benefit.

One option would be to survey posts from a particular time period to see what proportion would benefit. Obviously that doesn't cover posts that were never made because of the lack of MathJax, but it should give some idea.

Comment: I'm tempted to do that, but Jeff Atwood has not been seen in over 5 years.  I'm not convinced he represents the StackExchange team or the views of anyone in a position to make a change.  How does one ping the folks that control this forum?

Comment: @famsy the site moderators (i.e. me + others) can do it. What we'd need first is a debate on meta, e.g. a new answer to the existing post or a completely fresh post.